# How do I Encrypt Transaction Input Data Encode ABI

Tags: web3js, keccak

I'm buying erc20 token how can I encrypt my transaction input data . I using Javascript WEB3.JS method Can you help me with this?

like this when try on check etherscan. Warning: Unable to decode input data
Example:

> 0xc48fdfca000000000000000000000000fca59cd816ab1ead66534d82bc21e7515ce441cf00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Please explain with a practical example I have been searching this for about 3 days and I could not find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible since there's no encryption.

The first bytes in the data field are the function selector, ie `0xc48fdfca`.

For known selectors like `0xa9059cbb` (ERC20's transfer) Etherscan will decode the field.

Etherscan compute selectors mainly from registered contracts.

If you use an unregistered contract and the function wasn't used previously Etherscan won't be able to decode it.

Comment: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xdc0f9e8e58bc0956b7ed358708093aef1e44ab6ee607ad215b88c80059fff35d Check the input data available here exactly what I want and try to decode

Comment: @GökhanÖzdemir The signature `0xc48fdfca` isn't present in the public databases https://4byte.directory. Without the source code you will have to rever engineer the bytecode to understand the parameters and their purpose.